# i want to change my video in raw folder but it not accebt to play other video

Tags: java, android

This is my code. I want to change the vid in raw but it not accept another name

```
VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.mantvid);


videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
videoview.start();
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoview.setMediaController(mediaController);

mediaController.setAnchorView(videoview);
```

This is the error

```
error: cannot find symbol
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.manvid);
                                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable manvid
  location: class raw
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the following;

- Your file does not contain any capital letter or (-)
- Your file is not corrupted.
- Make a string variable and then pass it to the Uri.parse() like
  String path = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.manvid";

Comment: Thank you muaz I tried to delete the raw folder and created a new and changed the package name it's done thanks a lot

Comment: I am glad that it helped you.